# What all should they think about?

Tags: grammar

What all should they think about_ Is this sentence correct grammatically

Comment: It is not correct. I'm not sure what the "all" refers to. Are your trying to say, "What are all the things that they should think about?"

Comment: Welcome to EL&U! We're not a grammar checking service but if you need help learning English then [ell.stackexchange.com] can help. You might want to have a quick google at other sites to see what they say too.

Comment: But 'What should they (all) think about?' is probably what you're trying to say :)

Answer (score 1):

The nonstandard interrogative *what all* is found primarily in two varieties of English: Indian and American English in the South and to some degree in the historical Midwest.

In India, *what all* is the plural of *what* and will take a plural verb when used as the subject:

> 12.03.2018 ·[*What all*](https://brainly.in/question/2904981) are the grammar topics in hindi for class 10?
>
> [*What all*](https://www.lifealth.com/wellness/womens-health/what-all-are-the-facts-which-every-woman-must-know-about-fertility-sd/53078/) are the facts which every woman must know about fertility [?]
>
> Tamil Nadu bandh today: [*What all*](https://www.livemint.com/Politics/y0APxImFxT3nJBY2yQw9TN/Tamil-Nadu-bandh-tomorrow-What-will-remain-closed.html) are closed?

In those regions of the [United States](https://ygdp.yale.edu/phenomena/what-all) where the construction is common, the *all* signals the desire for a more or less comprehensive answer, i.e., a list or a complete description.  When the subject, it will take a singular verb:

> Headline: [*What all*](https://www.redefinedonline.org/2018/03/what-all-is-in-that-massive-florida-education-bill/) is in that massive Florida education bill?
>
> Headline: [*What All*](http://www.wvpolicy.org/what_all_is_in_the_road_funding_bill) is in the Road Funding Bill? ( West Virginia Center for Budget and Policy)
>
> [*What all*](http://thespringmortgageteam.com/what-all-is-included-in-closing-costs.html) is included in closing costs? (Real estate firm, McKinney TX)
>
> [*What all*](https://www.tripadvisor.co.nz/FAQ_Answers-g274874-d2252964-t2345585-What_all_is_in_the_gym_Is_there_a_pool.html) is in the gym? Is there a pool?

Once again, neither in India nor the US is this usage standard English, but it are not stigmatized except perhaps by those whose dialect doesn’t include the form. If you live in an area where the usage is common, feel free to use it in informal contexts, but not, say, in an academic essay or other formal writing.

Answer (score 0):

"What all" is a bit of a Midwestern or country phrase, but it's not proper English as far as I know. The more appropriate way of saying what you're asking would be the following.

> What should they think about?